# React... setting child Properties from State

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, reactjs

I have read that it is an anti-pattern to set state from props, but what about setting child properties from state?  Is this code okay, or is there a better practice.

Let's say we have an APP component that holds and changes it's state.  Is it good practice to pass that state down to child display components as props?

```
   var APP = React.createClass({

   getInitialState() {
       return {
           items: [1,2,3],
           title: 'Simple Sample'
       };
   },

   render() {
       return <div>
           <Display title={this.state.title} />
           <List items={this.state.items} />
       </div>
   }
});
```

What about something like this:

```
   var APP = React.createClass({

   getInitialState() {
       return {
           items: [1,2,3],
           title: 'Simple Sample'
       };
   },

   render() {
       return <div>
           <DisplayList {...this.state} />
       </div>
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing a parent's `state` into a child's `props` is the primary way of communicating with children. Passing function references to a child's `props` is the primary way of allowing the child to communicate back to the parent.

I personally avoid the `<DisplayList {...this.state} />` pattern because I prefer to be explicit about the `DisplayList`'s API and what props need to be passed. Passing the whole state can lead to subtle bugs when you add another variable later.

The antipattern you mention is *probably* the pattern of taking a component's `props` and copying them to that same component's `state`—it then becomes more difficult to figure out who owns the data, and whether you should call `setState` or call some method on `this.props`.